# Unity Gradle Build failed (Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] --> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters)

Tags: unity-game-engine, build.gradle

I can´t build my App for Android, Im always getting the following Error Code as you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx4J4.png)

I already tried fixing it by putting "android.overridePathCheck=true" in to the gradle.properties as it says in the Error Code. But that didn´t worked for me.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrp0G.png) is my build.gradle file where the Error occurs on line 24.

Comment: Why don't you change the project path? probably your project path contains empty space or some character that causes this error.

Comment: Tried it by changing the Name but that doesn´t work

Comment: Move your project to Any other path like C:/ or D:/. your user name contains a special character  may be the reason !  "Renè"